# Why is "agua" masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? "El agua" / "Las aguas" ¿Por qué decimos "el agua" si es una palabra femenina?

Tags: gramática, género, artículos, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

### English

Is there any rule that says that feminine nouns that start with "A" are converted to masculine or is it just done for phonetic (ie beauty) reasons?

Does this happen in all Spanish speaking countries?

---

### Spanish

¿Hay alguna regla que diga que los sustantivos femeninos que empiecen con "A" son convertidos a masculino, o solo se hace por motivos fonéticos o por belleza?

Comment: Same happens with "el arte" / "las artes".

Comment: Also happens with "el aguila" "las aguilas"

Comment: Well "el águila" "las águilas". The stressed á is the key that unlocks the article.

Comment: I want to stress: those feminine nouns are NOT converted to masculine; the rule is to use the masculine article, but the noun is still feminine (see Flimzy's answer).

Comment: @dusan actually, _el arte_ really is masculine (_el arte es bonito_), whereas _el agua_ is still feminine even though it takes _el_.

Comment: @guifa [Según DRAE, *arte* es de género ambiguo](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=arte) en el sentido de que hay casos en que se usa como palabra femenina y otros en que es masculina. Fíjate en *l**as** bell**as** artes*, por ejemplo, un caso donde — a mi parecer — la forma femenina es obligatoria. Sin embargo, yo diría *el arte nuev**o*** o *el arte modern**o*** sin pensar, pero no sé la regla operativa aquí, ni en mi mente ni en la realidad. :)

Comment: @tchrist tienes razón, yo siempre la he usado de acuerdo con el matiz normal moderno (masculino en singular «el arte», femenino en plural «las artes») pero el DPD lo admite en ambos géneros incluso para todos los significados.

Comment: @brazofuerte in [your revision](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/44/revisions) you mention Removed translation as per https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/. However, that Meta post (which I did not remember, by the way, and nobody enforced for the last 5 years) did apply to titles. In your latest edits you've been removing quite a lot of community effort coming from the [list of canonical questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) in which we decided to provide the English and Spanish version of posts. Let's seek some quorum in Meta before doing these changes

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' where was it decided to edit canonical questions to add translations of the bodies and titles? The only other post I found on meta was this, which had no support: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/should-we-translate-our-canonical-questions-into-english I'm not trying to start an edit war - I just thought the pages look really inelegant with walls of text repeating the same information, and will switch off most visitors from actually reading any of it. I think a cleaner solution would be to add a new question/answer in the other language if desired.

Comment: @brazofuerte that's a good one: me myself assumed it was based on an agreement, but definitely it was not (or I cannot find it). The thing is that [we consider the same question in English or Spanish to be duplicate](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2524/1674), so it we enforce this rule we would have to mark as a dupe. I'm not going to start an edit war neither, just wanted to see the rationale, and I think that it may be good to discuss over in Meta to find a good balance to fulfil the elegant aspect with the utility, etc. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: @brazofuerte there is a debate again about the language of the canonical posts. See Meta's [Should we translate our canonical questions into English?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4381/1674) if you want to participate. Let's try to find a good decision for all of us

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The noun "agua" is feminine (as you can see in the plural form "las aguas"), but **starts with a stressed "a"**. In this case, the preceding article must change for phonetic reasons: la -> el and una -> un.

The same happens with nouns which start with a stressed "ha" (ex: "el hacha"), but not with nouns which start with other vowels (ex: "la isla", "la épica", "la obra", "la uña").

The stress on the starting syllable is fundamental. In the feminine noun "la almohada", the stress is on the second "a", not on the starting one, so the article remains "la". Same for "la harina", whose stress is on the second syllable.

See also: [*El agua, esta agua, mucha agua*](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/el-agua-esta-agua-mucha-agua-0), by RAE.

Comment: There are two exceptions I know of offhand where the "la" is retained: "la a" and "la hache". Both are letters of the alphabet.

Comment: @KefSchecter, what you say about "hache" is quite similar to what happens with most words that begin with "h". For example: while you use "e" instead of "y" before a noun starting with i ("alemán e inglés"), you use "y" before a noun starting with "hi" ("agua y hielo"). Not sure why or how official, but that's how we do it :-)

Comment: @rsuarez, but you say "aguja e hilo". Maybe it's because "hielo" has a "ie" diphthong?

Comment: Just a little comment: That's the reason I don't like RAE, sorry for say it. The real derivation of the "la" is not "ille", is "illa". The real reason for the article "la" in masculine words that begin with 'a' is not for fonetic reason. The migration of this case from latin-middle spanish era-spanish is: Illa acqua - Il-acqua - El agua. "Il" was the preform of "El" (In latin, ille). Actually, so, this "el" in "el agua" has a "femenine nature" :D This happens because is a normal process of the evolution of a language: one "a" instead two.

Comment: And when I say "is not for fonetic reason" that really I want to mean is: we don't change "la" for "el" because it's sound better, is just because there was a fonetic migration between latin and spanish. Because we don't have contractions as italian, french, etc. We don't use "L' agua". There are only two contractions on spanish: "de+el=del" and "a+el=al"

Comment: @KefSchecter That's funny, since "El hacha" follows the commented rule.

Comment: Inaccurate. It's not for "a phonetic reason" and not only "with words" but with common names. I explain it in my answer.

Comment: It'd be nice to mention in the answer that the masculine article is also used with words which start with stressed "ha".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista feel free to edit my answer and add your note, thanks ;)

Answer (score 36):

*Agua* is always feminine, even in singular form.  However, to avoid the double 'a' sound in *la agua*, we use the article *el* in singular form.  In all other respects, *agua* is still feminine when singular.

For instance, when adding an adjective, you use the feminine form:

> the red water => *el agua roja*

The same is true for other feminine nouns that begin with a stressed 'a'.

Comment: Note that it’s ***el** agua pura* but ***la** pura agua*.  This is just something that happens.  It’s because of the articles that came from the Latin demonstratives, *ille/illa*.  It’s like saying ***an** apple* but ***a** big apple* in English. I really think you should explain the history of how this came to be, but perhaps this is not the right place for that? Seems like it would be.

Comment: ... with the funny exception: "la a" (i.e.: "la letra a")

Comment: @leonbloy It’s not an exception: letter-names in Spanish are always feminine, because as you observed, the tacit *letra* seeming key here. Letter-names are also feminine in Catalan, but not in Portuguese where they are masculine.

Comment: Would it still be correct to say "la agua"?  It seems like I have heard both "el agua" and "la agua" used.

Comment: @Wake - It's possible you've heard "la agua" on a rare occasion, I can't say because I wasn't there; but it's not correct.

Answer (score 17):

Actually it's not a gender reversal but a tradition that survives (inherited from Latin).

[The complete rules](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8Tu5qHMtQD63wEn6zW) are intrincate and arbitrary, kind of "well that sounds good to me", full of exceptions and even exceptions to the exceptions (see the variable use with toponyms or the "árbitra" or "árabe" cases). It is used with common names ("El ágata es una piedra preciosa") but not with proper nouns ("Ella ya no es la Ágata que conocí").

It has nothing to do with cacophony. Note:

> - **El** águila ávida se lanzó sobre la presa.
> - **La** ávida águila se lanzó sobre la presa.

Is it more cacophonic the first than the second word just because one is a noun and the other is an adjective? Oh, **we all** forgot to say that the article change must be used *with nouns but not with adjectives*.

It's sometimes said that this way it's easier to pronounce. What about this?

> —¿Qué es ese papel?
>   —El alta.
>
> —¿Cuál es tu hija?
>   —La alta.

You will see that you can pronounce both sentences without being damaged (at least permanently).

Ask me and I will answer "let it disappear". At least, the academicians might let it be optional. I think it's good for nothing more than confusing people to make them say:

> - Nunca digas «de [image: esta]**este** agua no beberé».
> - A [image: buena]**buen** hambre no    hay pan duro.
> - [image: La nueva]**El nuevo** aula es más grande.

It should be:

> - Nunca digas «de **esta** agua no beberé».
> - A **buena** hambre no hay pan duro.
> - **La nueva** aula es más grande.

Comment: The first half of the answer is very interesting however the "este agua" and "nuevo aula" examples at the end sound wrong to me and make this answer confusing. In the DPD reference on paragraph 2.1 it is clear that "aula" is feminine, is noun and starts with stressed 'a' so you should say "el aula" however being feminine you should say "la nueva aula". Also you can find at the "Instituto Cervantes" site a reference to ["de **esta agua** no beberé](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59245&Lng=0) I don't think is right to leave that part there.

Comment: The asterisk means it's incorrect. Sorry, I did not make it clear. That's the point: this outdated (it's latin) and nonsensical (incoherent) rule makes people say things like those (I've _heard_ them all). That's because they end thinking that words like _agua_, _hambre_ or _aula_ are masculine.

Comment: So the problem is that the first and last are wrong (correctly marker) but second is right (incorrectly marked) because it is right to say [**a buen hambre** no hay pan duro](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58039&Lng=0)

Comment: No, [**it's not**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=hambre): "pero los adjetivos deben ir en forma femenina". Note that "buen" is an adjective and it should be "buena". The change before the noun is mandatory with "la" or "una" and optative with "alguna" or "ninguna" but it _never_ concerns adjectives. Thanks for the link. It proves that the rule it's so toxic that it confuses even people in the CVC!

Comment: My brain still don't like it hahaha. Anyway I think this is the most complete answer of all +1

Comment: The question now is: why doesn't **`La Haya`** follow this rule?

Comment: Follow the link I provided at the beginning of my answer and you'll find that is one of the exceptions. Maybe because "Haya" it's a proper noun here, just like in my example "la Ágata".

Comment: Un ejemplo de muchísimos: [El Ayuntamiento de Oropesa del Mar abre **un nuevo** aula infantil de 1 a 2 años y mantiene otra de 2 a 3 años](https://i.imgur.com/Gd194Iq.png).

Comment: As to 'letting it disappear' or the academicians letting it 'be optional', it's useful to remember that academicians don't make rules for language (much as they might try). Language, through its speakers, makes its own rules. When usage eliminates this gender (word class) ambivalence, which it eventually may well do, the academic rules will acquiesce and reflect it.

Comment: cacophonous is the word.

Comment: ‘Latin’ on its own generally refers to Classical Latin in English, which had no definite articles at all. As such, saying that this is inherited from ‘Latin’ is misleading. It is inherited from Old Spanish, certainly; from Late Latin, probably; and possibly even from earlier forms of Vulgar Latin – but certainly not from Classical Latin.

Answer (score 8):

## The rule

> If a feminine noun begins with a stressed `/a/` sound, some* singular articles/determiners:
>
> - *la, una, alguna, ninguna*
>
> take a masculine form if they occur directly before the noun:
>
> - *el, un, algún, ningún*

Nominally this affects **all words with stressed initial `/a/`:**

| Prefix | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| "a-" | *Asia, acta, agua, ala, alga, alma, alza, ama, ancla, anda, ansa, ansia, ara, arca, arda, aria, arma, arpa, arria, asa, ascua, asna, aspa, asta, aula, aura, aya, ave, arte (m/f)* |
| "á-" | *África, ácana, áfaca, ágata, ágora, águila, álaga, álala, álgebra, álica, álula, ámpula, áncora, ánfora, ánima, árdea, área, árgana, árgoma, árnica, árula, áspera, ática* |
| "ha-" | *haba, habla, haca, hacha, hada, halda, hampa, harca, harda, harma, harpa, harria, haya, haza, hambre, haz* |
| "há-" | *hálara* |

With the following exceptions:

| Exceptions | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| Letters | *la a, la hache, la alfa, el/la álef* |
| Acronyms | *la ASA, la APA* etc |
| Proper names | *la Ana, la Ángela, la Austria, la Ávila, la Ámsterdam, la Haya* etc **Continents:** *el Asia, el África* |
| Nominalized adjectives | *la alta, la árida* etc |
| (Some) fem. nouns with fem. subjects | *la árbitra* |
| Common gender nouns with fem. subjects | *la árabe, la ácrata, la alto* (singer) |

## In practice: a bit more complicated

As [the comments](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment23397_17302) on cdlvcdlv's answer show, among native speakers there is a tendency (despite the RAE's prescriptions) to treat words like *agua* as 'hermaphroditic' - postnomial modifiers are consistently treated as feminine, but prenomial modifiers show considerable fluctuation in gender.

This treatment of *agua*-like words isn't limited to casual speech, but is also found in educated speakers and formal/academic writing:

> ¿Con qué derecho se la toma por **aquel**<sup>m</sup> **asa** y no por **ésta**<sup>f</sup>?
>
> - *Ortega y Gasset*, 1983

> ... los desperfectos que **el**<sup>m</sup> abundante **agua caída**<sup>f</sup> provocó en las vías...
>
> - *Vuelve*, 2007

> ... **nuestro**<sup>m</sup> **habla riojana**<sup>f</sup> actual...
>
> - *Martínez Sáenz de Jubera y González Perujo*, 1998

> The first thing to note is that variation in gender agreement with nouns of this class generally affects determiners and adjectives preceding, but usually not following, the noun. For example, a search of 20th century texts in *Corpus del
> español* (Davies n.d.) returns examples such as *mismo agua* 'same water', *propio agua* 'own water', *mucho agua* 'a lot of water', but no examples where a postposed adjective with *agua* is masculine. Counting both 19<sup>th</sup> and 20<sup>th</sup> century examples there are three tokens of *buen alma* ‘good soul’ in the corpus versus two of *buena alma*, whereas no tokens are found of *alma bueno* in comparison to 17 for *alma buena*. That is, for some speakers some of these nouns variably condition one type of gender agreement with prenominal modifiers and the other type with postnominal modifiers.
>
> - [*El abundante agua fría: Hermaphroditic Spanish Nouns*](http://linguistics.byu.edu/faculty/deddingt/el_abundante_agua.pdf) (2008)

The hypothesized reasoning for native speakers internalizing this hermaphroditic treatment of *agua*-like words is the learning of tokens such as *el agua* and *agua fría* (recognising *el* as a masculine article and not an allomorph of *la*) and analogy to other such words.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that this is also used for words starting with *h* followed by an *a*: 'El hada madrina / Las hadas madrinas'.
The idea as many others have said is to avoid two consecutive *a* that are (somehow) hard to pronounce and produce a what is called "*cacofonía*".

Another important issue (a commonly forgotten one) is that the gender of the word does not mean that the designated object has that same gender. This causes discussion as if the correct way is "*el abogado*", "*la abogado*" or "la abogada".

Answer (score 2):

#### English

*'Agua'* is feminine by definition (as RAE explains in [*El agua, esta agua, mucha agua*](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/el-agua-esta-agua-mucha-agua-0)). The article *'el'* is used to avoid stressing of two consecutive identical letters (note that this doesn't happen with all nouns that begin with *'a'*). And yes, in this case all Spanish-speaking countries do change the article *'la'* for *'el'* for the previous reason.

#### Español

*'Agua'* es femenino por definición (como la RAE explica en [*El agua, esta agua, mucha agua*](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/el-agua-esta-agua-mucha-agua-0)). El articulo *'el'* es usado para prevenir el arrastre de la vocal (esto no ocurre con todos los sustantivos que inician con *'a'*). Y sí, en este caso todos los países hablantes del español cambian el articulo *'la'* por *'el'* por ese mismo motivo.

---

**More info / Más información:**

- http://spanish.about.com/cs/grammar/a/genderreversal.htm