# What is the gender of adjectives that describe implied nouns?

Tags: méxico, adjetivos, género

I went to a Mexican restaurant and this is how my conversation went:

> **Yo**: Quiero un vaso de agua de sandía.
>
> **Camarera**: ¿Chica o Grande?
>
> **Yo**: Chica.

Why did the waitress use "chica" instead of "chico"? Isn't she asking me how big of a cup I want? Cup is masculine, so I would presume that the adjective describing it should also be masculine. The waitress also used the same feminine "chica" with the next customer, so I doubt she botched up the word.

In general, how do you decide on the gender of an adjective when its noun is implied?

Comment: It should be "chico" because she is talking about the cup which is masculine.

Comment: @JorgeCampos tienes razon, nunca me habia puesto a pensarlo.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio El `vaso` sale sobrando :) La mesera, en este caso, pensó en la manera común de ordenar de la gente "me da un agua, chica/mediana/grande".

Comment: Isn't *jugo de sandía* a better phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not incorrect and actually you asked what you shuld have to. But people use to refer to "vaso de agua" as just "agua"

> e.g. *¿Me da un agua de sandía? Chica, por favor.*
>     (when a standard unit is understood: e.g. *vaso* or *jarra*)

Imagine the lot of times a waitress deal with the expression `vaso grande/chico de agua`. It's totally correct, but just too long to be pronounced 10 times/hour. Waitress and costumers use the more confortable expression "agua chica/grande", provided there is no missunderstanding whether we are referring to `jarra` or `vaso`.

So, in your example,

> **Usted**: Quiero un vaso de agua de sandía.
>   **Camarera**: ¿(agua) chica o grande?
>   **Usted**: (agua) chica.

What if you didn't have asked that? A possible conversation is

> **Usted**: Quiero un agua grande de sandía.
>   **Camarera**: ¿Jarra o vaso?
>   **Usted**: Vaso.
>   **Camarera**: ¿chico o grande?
>   **Usted**: Chico.

Comment: Isn't agua masculine too because it starts with a stressed "a"? El agua.

Comment: "Agua" is femenine. `El agua limpia`, `mucha agua`. You might be interested in http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la

Comment: agua    f. Sustancia líquida - "el" used to make it easier to pronounce. Try saying la agua

Comment: It's similar to french `mon amie` -- `amie` is femenine, and one changes the article `ma` to `mon` to avoid a cacophony.

Comment: So I was wrong to include *vaso*? I asked my Mexican contractor (Immigrant, not Chicano) how to order *aguas frescas* and that's how he told me to say it. He explained to me how *vaso* was the correct size, while *copa* and *taza* were wrong.

Comment: @JoJo Both are right, `vaso de agua` is right, indeed, and the correctness is indisputable. The point is that `agua chica` is also correct. The waitress had in mind what most people ask for: `deme un agua chica`, when they are familiar with the univoquous meaning of this last expression.

Comment: @Jojo yes, and `taza` und `copa` would be wrong.

Comment: "Vaso de agua" does imply tap water in some countries, If you just say "agua" you may get a bottled water.

Answer (score 3):

It's always the same gender, she messed it up.

Being a native Spanish speaker with good orthography, I see that usually even the native speakers make silly mistakes (especially in verb conjugation), just let it pass through.

**Edit:** Further explanation from the comments: "Quiero un vaso de agua de sandía.",  Quiero un vaso de agua de sandía; el sujeto de la oración es Yo, pero es un sujeto tácito, donde tú tienes que inferir cuál pronombre es, y el resto es el predicado, el núcleo de predicado es el sustantivo "vaso" y "de agua" es simplemente un complemento (y comienza con "de", que de por sí es una preposición). Así que la pregunta correcta es "¿Chico o grande?".

Comment: If most native speakers consistently make the same mistake, then a descriptive linguist will cease to consider it a mistake.   A prescriptive linguist might continue to consider the prevailing usage as "new" and "degraded".  Take your pick.

Comment: I'd go for prescriptive. Also, I've never heard this specific mistake ("chica" for glass) other than here.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong, of course you'd say: "¿cómo te gustaría tu agua?" and it'd be "tu vaso de agua", but if you actually analyze the sentence that the one that asked provided, the nucleus of the predicate is "vaso".

Comment: @superpatosainz `chica` does't stand for glass, it is an adjective attached to `agua`. I tried to explain that in the answer.

Comment: Refer to my edit on why the correct question would be "¿chico o grande?".

Comment: @superpatosainz that's beyond the point. I agree with your grammar analysis, but I don't agree with you considering it to be a mistake. The waitress used a synonim on talking, and just substituted `vaso de agua chica/grande` for the hugely more common expression `agua chica/grande`. That's it. There is no error.

Comment: Well, yea, in a more relaxed way it is just a trivial mistake. But if we are talking about speaking properly and formally, demonstrating your good civility, I think matters.