# ¿Existen en castellano sustantivos masculinos en singular que en plural tengan los dos géneros (m y f)?

Tags: sustantivos, género, plurales, latín

En italiano, los sustantivos de algunas partes del cuerpo que son dos o más (orejas, dedos, brazos) son masculinos en singular, mientras que en plural pueden ser ambos masculinos o femeninos pero con significado diferente. Eso no pasa solo con partes del cuerpo.

Es una herencia del latín donde estos sustantivos eran neutros y fueron asimilados por ambos los géneros como terminaban en *-a* al plural.

Estudié español durante mucho tiempo pero aún no encuentro alguno (en italiano se llaman sustantivos superabundantes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hay tales palabras. El origen de la ambigüedad de estas palabras en italiano es la reinterpretación del sufijo plural *-a* de las palabras neutras como un sufijo femenino.

e.g.

- `n.s.` *brachium* > `m.s.` *il braccio* (> `m.pl.` *i bracci*)
- `n.pl.` *bracia* > `f.pl.` *le braccia*

En castellano, los plurales se forman añadiendo *-[e]s* a la palabra, así que no hay razón morfológica para cambiar de género entre singular y plural:

- `n.s.` *brachium* > `m.s.` *el brazo* > `m.pl.` *los brazos*
- `n.pl.` bracia > ...

Algo similar sí pasa con palabras femeninas que empiezan con un fonema `/a/` tónico:

- `f.s.` el agua
- `f.pl` las aguas

Pero la forma **los aguas* no es gramatical, y prescriptivamente la forma singular es también de género femenino,  independientemente del articulo.

---

<sup>- [Italian language SE: **Can a noun have two definite articles?**](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9233/4183) (section: Latin Neuter)</sup>
<sup>- [Why is “agua” masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? “El agua” / “Las aguas”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25868/18348)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

En realidad, arte es masculino en el singular y femenino en el plural

Comment: Seria mejor explicar con mas detalles.

Comment: @mdewey Necesita más detalle, pero podría ser el germen de una buena respuesta. https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1163704460167786496

Comment: Para responder a la pregunta debería ser "el arte" (masculino en singular) y valor tanto "los artes" como "las artes" en plural. Para saber más: [Why is it “el arte moderno” and “las artes finas”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15702/5481). Creo que esta aportación es más un comentario que una respuesta, a menos que haga el esfuerzo de explicar algo (aunque en todo caso pasaría a ser probablemente una mala respuesta o incompleta)