# Why do we have both "el arte moderno" and "el arte métrica"? What is the historical origin of this redundancy?

Tags: etimología, historia, género, lingüística, ambigüedad

In "el agua fría", we have to use the article "el" because of the stressed "a". The same thing is seen in "el arte métrica".

Now in "el arte métrica", I can see this convention interacting with a bizarre one. I noticed that in the plural, we always have "las artes métricas", but in the singular, we have "el arte moderno" and "el arte métrica".

My questions are:

1. What is the origin of these two distinct genders? Did Latin have a
   more practical reason for having two different genders for the same word?
2. Why hasn't modern Spanish reformed this redundancy, just using "el arte moderna"
   everywhere ? Most other aspects of Spanish gender seem to be completely coherent. See a related post [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15702/why-is-it-el-arte-moderno-and-las-artes-finas?).

Comment: The proper term is el arte moderno because arte is masculin. The other is a mistake.

Comment: @Lambie https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/arte "This word may be used as a feminine or masculine noun in the singular, but must be used as a feminine noun in the plural."

Comment: in the plural, it's las artes modernas. Beware that arte does have two meanings in Spanish.  But no one says: la arte moderna **referring to painting** etc, they do say: una arte complicada. etc. but that is the other meaning of arte, which is craft, and which is feminine. Look in the RAE before asking. These things are all there. https://dle.rae.es/arte la arte métrica: poetic craft.

Comment: Here is a long-winded explanation of it: https://assets.cambridge.org/97811071/44729/excerpt/9781107144729_excerpt.pdf

Comment: @Lambie RAE says in your link that all meanings of "arte" can be both masculine or feminine...

Comment: @wimi No, they are not all both. And the ones that are both, would be art OR craft in English. Some are only masculine and some are only feminine. Others can take a m or f adjective. So decorative arts and decorative crafts. But I would not know which is which in Spanish.

Comment: https://www.rae.es/dpd/arte is more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the curiosities I like to sometimes think about. So, to my knowledge, there aren't that many words that can be both masculine or feminine. Arte is even more special case, because it is mostly used masculine, and in feminine it is used for the 'craft' meaning of the word. Although, sometime in plural it is feminine too ('las bellas artes'). So it varies a lot. For that reason a lot of natives will see it as a mistake if they see it in feminine. Another word that sort of changes meaning with gender used is 'dote'. Coming from the old tradition of giving gifts to a woman someone wanted to marry. 'La dote' referred to the tradition, and 'el dote' was referring to the gift itself, to my understanding.

Other notable examples are medical 'autoclaves', 'azúcar'-sugar like 'azúcar morena' but often referred as 'el azúcar', 'internet'-internet, 'interrogante'-question, and 'mar'-sea as the most notable one; comes to mind a lot of poems talking about 'la mar'.

In conclusion, it is mostly special cases and you won't find it much often. Reasons often vary, mostly because of use. Some of those words just get assigned different gender in different Spanish speaking regions. Some are just new words like internet, so it has to get a gender assigned and because of talking about a net or a 'red', people would want to use feminine form. And lastly, no native speakers will get teached word genders. Often you correct children if they assign a strange gender to a word. This means that the gender a word will get is the one their community uses. As a result, there are regions that say things as 'la radio' which I don't know if it well get accepted as correct, or the really incorrect use of 'la calor' which is used widely by native speakers in Mexico. As I have seen in my life, incorrect uses if popular enough, will get accepted as time goes on, or specified as regional use of a word.

Comment: Almost forgot, another rule that will confuse with this exceptions, words starting with letter 'a' will get this plural as feminine and singular as masculine article, for accent reasons. The other words I posted, not only articles can be both genders used, they are also correctly gendered with both adjectives genders.

Comment: Yes, I had already said the thing about craft versus art.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sin profundizar en los robustos e interesantes temas de filología histórica y las distintas referencias al diccionario, tal y como han sido presentadas y oportunamente resueltas en los comentarios, los cuales ayudan a obtener una mejor comprensión de los términos, intentare dentro de la dificultad del tema, completar los cambios del concepto que sobre "**el arte y las artes**" se han producido. *Siento su extensión*.

[image]

1.- El origen actual de los distintos modos de entender la palabra "arte" se encuentra en la evolución a lo largo de la historia de la propia palabra "**ars**". "*Plus artis quam fidei adhibere*" ((demostrar más habilidad que buena fe). Donde el "**arte**" era **entendido como una habilidad o destreza**.

1.- En latín "**ars**" era solo femenino, no masculino. En **singular** "**Ars**" solo se entendía como ciencia o actividad sometida a la razón y que tenía objeto de adquirir ciertas habilidades siguiendo unas reglas, preceptos o guías especificas, a través de las cuales, se alcanzaba el objetivo deseados.  En el **plural** latino, con el término "**Artēs**", se referían a las cualidades intelectuales o morales "*bonae artes animi et corporis*" (buenas artes morales y físicas (donde "artes" tiene el sentido de piezas o prendas)), "**malae artes**" ((las) malas artes (eran (los) malos vicios)).

En su evolución temporal, el mismo concepto tradicional de **arte** fue cultivado durante la Edad Media, a través de las disciplinas académicas, los oficios profesionales, los oficios viles y mecánicos (**artes liberales-artes serviles**), y donde aún se entendía el "**arte**" como cualquier habilidad del hombre en el terreno productivo. "**Arte entendido como oficio**", para el que se precisaba aprender y desarrollar ciertas destrezas vinculadas. Así eran artistas eran tanto el cocinero, el jardinero o el constructor.  La pintura por ejemplo era tenida por manualidad y por tanto, no se encontraba dentro de las disciplinas de las artes liberales (Trivium y Quadrivium) y aún tardara un tiempo, pues se la consideraba una disciplina advenediza situada en las artes mecánicas y segundonas.

Sin embargo, esto comenzó a cambiar a partir del **Renacimiento**, y particularmente con el "**Manierismo**", en este sentido, el "**Manierismo**" **es el momento en que el** "**artista**" (*Manierismo, a la manera del artista*), **deja a un lado las rígidas reglas establecidas para dejarse llevar por sus propios gustos estéticos**, alejándose de esta manera de lo que hasta ese momento era lo verosímil y verdadero, para desde entonces, desarrollar una imaginación e irrealidad cada vez más fantasiosa, dotando a los elementos que le rodean de una abstracción que va prescindiendo poco a poco de la mayoría de las cualidades que lo hacían distinguibles para los demás.

[image]

*Antigua utilización de la palabra "Arte", "**La Arte**" en femenino singular.*

---

A partir de aquel momento, lentamente y sin proponerlo, **el concepto de "Arte" va a ir dividiéndose en dos**;

- Por una parte se encuentra el novedoso concepto de aquello que hoy conocemos por "**artístico**", "**el arte experimentado a través del gusto del artista"**, cada vez más libre, mediante el cual se expresan las ideas, emociones y visiones de aquel o de sus benefactores (Mecenas), en un mundo donde la consideración por los deleites y placeres que otorga la belleza y lo bello va en aumento, un auge de gran importancia que tomará este nuevo sentido estético y emotivo de "**El arte**" como valor cultural y de riqueza al mismo tiempo, dentro de una sociedad cada vez más sofisticada.
- Por otro lado, el viejo y arraigado concepto de "**Arte**" que hace referencia al "**Arte como Técnica**" y a los oficios, donde las destrezas, habilidades y principios aún se hallan sometidos a normas y pautas, con reglas concebidas para realizar cada actividad en su caso.

[image]

*Aludiendo a la fantasía e irrealidad de la que se compone "**El Arte**".*

**Las Artes como Las Ciencias**

El intento del recién llegado "**Arte, como obra cultural**" por desplazar el sentido tradicional de "**Arte como Técnica**", harán que los preceptos normativos de este último se vean entroncados en el inicio del Renacimiento con los principios de la "**Ciencia**" tal y como la entendemos actualmente, pues los conceptos "técnicos" tradicionales del "**Arte**" en su definición estaban formados por modelos y patrones ordenados en cuanto a su saber empírico y teórico, tomando en la idea de "**La Ciencia" y "Las Ciencias**" (únicamente en femenino), las nociones "**técnicas**" **de permanencia que paulatinamente irían quedando dentro de los fundamentos de las** "**Las Artes**" (femenino plural), hasta llegar a nuestros días y que llevan implícita la idea tradicional.

[image]

*Durante un tiempo "**Las Ciencias y Las Artes**" compartieron las nociones técnicas, teóricas y empíricas comunes entre ambas.*

En ese tiempo  tanto "**Las Ciencias**" como "**Las Artes**" eran ese tipo de conocimiento que las personas podían compartir y comunicar entre sí.

[image]

*Las obras de este género solían representar objetos de arte junto con otros elementos como instrumentos científicos o especímenes naturales particulares.*

---

2.- En la **ambigüedad limitada** de la palabra "**arte**" aún queden viejos vestigios en otras voces del antiguo idioma que no tienen esa limitación. Así la **ambigüedad** se entiende en las palabras, cuando el singular puede construirse tanto en masculino como en femenino, y decimos para "mar", "**el mar**" / "**la mar salada**", para "azúcar" "**el azúcar**"/ "**la azúcar tostada**" o para "dote" "**el dote**" / "**la dote generosa**".

**Las Justificaciones de la Palabra "Arte" que Confunden**

Ese aparente equivoco se ha tratado justificar, de formas variadas, así de tener la palabra "**arte**" una ambigüedad limitada y algo extraña, donde en singular se emplea el masculino "**El Arte**" y en plural el femenino "**Las Artes**";

- Se trataría entonces de justificarla a través de la sinalefa (*unión de la vocal o vocales finales de una palabra con la vocal o vocales iniciales de la siguiente, de modo que forman una única sílaba tanto a efectos fonéticos como métricos*), así se dice que es una forma de evitar que la "**a**" de "l**a** **á**guila" (el águila) o "l**a** **a**gua" (el agua), confluyan. Sin embargo aunque existen ejemplos más claros de sinalefa (*y encuanto del**a** **a**rte*), en este caso, "l**a** **a**zúcar tostada", "l**a** **a**zúcar blanca", no hemos pasado a decir "*lazúcar*".
- Razones de eufonía, (*efecto acústico agradable que resulta de la combinación de sonidos en una palabra o en una frase*), de esta manera decir "el águila" o "el agua" resultaría más agradable para el oído que "la azúcar blanca".
- Otra justificación, incluida en el esbozo de una nueva gramática de la lengua española, es que los plurales, al imponer un determinado género, pueden asociar diferencias frente al singular, con lo que más que aclarar confunde aún más.

2.- Actualmente el uso de la palabra "**Arte**" tiene en español un **carácter ambiguo**, no así en el portugués o en el italiano donde la palabra "**Arte**" es de género femenino.  En el español actual para "**El Arte**" se podría pensar que es un convencionalismo en el mismo sentido que palabras como "**el alma**", "**el agua**", "**el arma**","**el águila**"... por lo que se puede actualmente decir, en el caso del "arte", "**el arte**", pero **no** "**la arte**", "**las artes**" pero no "**los artes**". Sin embargo, son las razones expuestas con anterioridad las que nos han llevado a la actual situación, donde se arrastran las normas pero no se recuerda como se ha producido este paulatino cambio. El español moderno más que pretender reformar la redundancia ha sufrido en este tiempo una evolución al mantener distintas característica dentro de la propia palabra "Arte" segmentando o fragmentando sus rudimentos según se utilice el masculino singular "**El Arte**", o el plural femenino, **"Las Artes**".

**Diccionario panhispánico de dudas**

> **En el español actual, si se usa en femenino singular**, **debe llevar la
> forma "el" del artículo**, por ser palabra que comienza por /a/ tónica: "**el
> arte poética**", no la arte poética.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/arte

---

**Distinción Actual entre "El Arte y Las Artes" o como Evitar la Confusión.**

La RAE con respecto al "**Arte en femenino**" nos dice;

> "No obstante, con el sentido preciso de **"conjunto de normas y
> principios para hacer bien algo**", **es normalmente femenino, incluso
> en singular,** y así se habla de arte amatoria, arte cisoria ( *el
> arte de cortar, recortar, escindir o trinchar con herramientas tales
> como cuchillos, tijeras, escalpelos...*), arte métrica o arte
> poética".
>
> https://www.rae.es/dpd/arte

Por tanto, cuando empleamos "**el arte**" en sentido femenino ya sea en singular como en plural, nos estamos refiriendo **al arte** ** en el cual se incluye su sentido técnico**.

[image]

*La palabra "Arte" con el sentido normativo o preceptivo.*

Así en las charlas informales, por ejemplo hablando de "**El arte de la pesca**" o "**Las artes de pesca**" actualmente estaríamos refiriéndonos no solo al aspecto inmaterial e intelectual que lleva consigo el concepto de "**El arte de la pesca**" sino que en una profundidad mayor sobre el mismo, estaríamos también aludiendo tanto a los métodos utilizados en la captura y extracción de los peces en su medio natural, como a las diferentes técnicas de pesca para cada una de sus modalidades. (*"La Ciencia Pesquera" sería la disciplina académica de gestión y comprensión de la pesca como ciencia multidisciplinar*).

De esta manera cuando utilizamos generalmente el plural, por ejemplo en conceptos como, "Las Artes Visuales", "Las Artes Escénicas", "Las Artes Poéticas"... también estamos aludiendo a la idea de "**las artes**" con su antiguo significado griego, **τέχνη**, téchnē, latín "**technicus**" "**la técnica como arte**", en donde la noción no solo se centra en el pensamiento artístico e intelectual sino también en las habilidades y destrezas de las variadas técnicas que atienden a las distintas artes enumeradas.

**Como Resumen**

- Actualmente "**La Arte**" en singular no se dice en español, sino "**El Arte**" o "**Las Artes**".

[image]

*Pero toda **la arte del benar** / Et quanto **dela arte de pescar**...*

- "**El Arte**" en singular masculino, es la actividad humana que tiene como fin la creación de obras culturales y manifiesta en la actualidad el concepto artístico, intelectual, emotivo, estético e inspirador de una visión general del mundo y que el propio arte como noción de civilización y pensamiento social expresa guiado por la mano de los propios "artistas", "**El Arte** gráfico", "**El Arte** Plástico", "**El Arte** Abstracto", "**El Arte** Decorativo" (Pintura y Escultura  destinadas al embellecimiento de objetos o edificios), "**El Arte** Bella" (cualquiera de las que tienen por objeto expresar la belleza), "**El Arte** Militar" (destreza para comandar un ejército,), "**El Arte** Cisoria"...
- Aunque en otros tiempos no fue así, **en el español actual**, cuando se usa la palabra  "arte" en plural, "**artes**", adopta la forma femenina "Las artes".
- "**Las Artes** **en plural femenino o El arte en femenino singular**" (Las Artes de Pesca, El Arte de Pesca) envuelven como concepto todo lo que rodea a "**El Arte**" como noción y símbolo artístico, intelectual, emotivo e inspirador del tipo de actividad o "Arte" al que se refieran, englobando las diversas disciplinas estéticas y así mismo al conjunto de normas y principios técnicos correspondientes que las habilidades y destrezas precisan para que lleguen a hacerlo bien en su realización.

---

---

---

**ANEXO**

- Téngase en cuenta que en época antigua, por ejemplo, la poesía no era considerada un arte y la pintura no estaba incluida dentro de las artes liberales del "Trivium y el Quadrivium".
- Por otro lado aunque aún continua la discusión, se entiende que "**ARTE MODERNO**" fue un movimiento artístico, iniciado en el S.XIX hasta mediados del S.XX, al que más tarde entre otros, le seguiría el "ARTE POSMODERNO", años 70', siendo considerado en general lo demás "Arte Contemporáneo" o "Actual" para referirse a algo de moda, actual o novedoso de nuestros días, de ahí todavía aquella discusión.
- Lo que si se puede decir en español, aunque es menos usual y lleva a confusión, es "**SALA DE ARTE MODERNA**" en el sentido de "SALA MODERNA DE ARTE", "GALERIA DE ARTE MODERNA", en el sentido de "GALERIA MODERNA DE ARTE" o "**Es una obra de Arte moderna**", donde "**moderna**" tiene el significado de "pertenecer a una época reciente o actual", pues una obra de arte actual no tiene porqué pertenecer al movimiento del "**ARTE MODERNO**".
- Comentar al hilo, que en portugués y en italiano si se puede decir "**ARTE MODERNA**", en su sentido artístico, ya que "**Arte**" es femenino. Ejemplos "**Museu de **Arte Moderna** do Rio de Janeiro**", La Galleria Nazionale d'**Arte Moderna** e Contemporanea (Roma).

[image]

*Mapa del Museu de **Arte Moderna** do Rio de Janeiro.*

- Por último, respecto a la referencia de "**El Arte Métrica**"  Si se dijera "El Arte Métrico", podría confundirse con el concepto intelectual de las medidas de superficie en cualquier campo de la medición, al decir "El Arte Métrica", no tiene confusión, pues consiste en el estudio de los versos y las estrofas que componen los poemas.
- "**Las Artes Métricas", "El Arte (de la) Métrica" o "Artes Poéticas**" se refieren tanto al concepto intelectual abstracto general, como al particular, que puede englobar a las distintas disciplinas describiendo las reglas y elementos generales y necesarios dentro de las técnicas propias según los distintos tipos de poemas o su composición, tales como Odas, Elegías, Sátiras, Romances, Églogas..., en los que se llevan a cabo los distintos estudios y composiciones poéticas.

/ Para medir un verso hay que tener en cuenta la sinalefa (*unión de la vocal o vocales finales de una palabra con la vocal o vocales iniciales de la siguiente, de modo que forman una única sílaba tanto a efectos fonéticos como métricos*) y la acentuación de la palabra final del verso.

/ Si el verso termina en palabra aguda se cuenta una sílaba más.

/ Si el verso termina en palabra llana se queda el verso igual.

/ Si el verso termina en palabra esdrújula se cuenta una sílaba menos.

/ etc

- En la antigüedad si era posible decir "El Arte" o "La Arte", "Los Artes" o "Las Artes" provocando con ello quizás más confusión.

[image]

*La palabra "Artes", "**Los Artes**", con el sentido de elementos e instrumentos de pesca. (Fitóra es tridente, Canguíl es alimento o cebo*

[image]

*La palabra "Arte", "**La Arte**", en femenino singular. "La arte de imprimir libros"*

---