# ¿Es justificado el uso de los artículos definidos y decir por ejemplo "todos los espacios interiores... deben ser llenados con *la* agua"?

Tags: traducción, artículos

Lo siguiente es una parte de la traducción técnica, donde los artículos definidos en negritas parecen ¿Por qué fue necessario usar tantas ***las***?

> ...la altura máxima de aspiración **de la** agua de refrigeración (antes de arrancar el motor diesel, todos los espacios interiores de la bomba hidráulica deben ser llenados con **la** agua)...

Comment: No. Ambas frases son incorrectas....  ...la altura máxima de aspiración d̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶ **del** agua de refrigeración (antes de arrancar el motor diesel, todos los espacios interiores de la bomba hidráulica deben ser llenados con  ̶l̶a̶ agua)...

Comment: @DGaleano Y ¿por qué la palabra es utilisada en masculino en el primero caso, y sino el artículo en la segunda frase?

Comment: Cuando la palabra comienza por [a] tónica se cambia en el singular por el masculino. El agua/Las aguas, el águila/las águilas.  See https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la  En la segunda frase es "genérico"y no necesita artículo. Si el agua que debe usarse es "específica" se pude usar el articulo [el] ej: ...los espacios interiores de la bomba deben llenarse con **el** agua que teníamos reservada para esto.

Comment: @dgaleano eso se ve como la respuesta correcta a la interrogante original

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "agua" masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? "El agua" / "Las aguas"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la)

Comment: @walen sugerencia aceptada :-)

Comment: @Gorpik no creo que sea duplicada. La pregunta era sobre porque utilizar tantas veces el artículo (a pesar de que estaba utilizando el articulo equivocado) y no sobre si se usa el masculino o el femenino. Igual habria podido preguntar porque tantos **el**

Comment: @DGaleano De acuerdo, quito mi voto.

Answer (score 6):

No. Ambas frases son incorrectas y se corrigen como sigue:

> ...la altura máxima de aspiración d̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶ del agua de refrigeración (antes de arrancar el motor diesel, todos los espacios interiores de la bomba hidráulica deben ser llenados con ̶l̶a̶ agua)...

¿Por qué se cambia por el masculino?: Cuando la palabra comienza por [a] tónica se cambia en el singular por el masculino. Ej: *El agua/Las aguas*, *el águila/las águilas*. Ver [Why is “agua” masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? “El agua” / “Las aguas”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la)

En la segunda frase se habla del agua en "genérico" y por lo tanto no necesita artículo. Si el agua que debe usarse es "específica" se pude usar el articulo **el**, por ejemplo:

> ... los espacios interiores de la bomba deben llenarse con **el** agua *que teníamos reservada para esto.*