# Duda sobre "el arma". Curioso caso de cambio de artículos

Tags: gramática

Me llama la atención esta palabra, porque suelo verla con el artículo erróneo en los medios de comunicación, libros e incluso en películas. Sin embargo, me gustaría saber por qué ocurre lo siguiente:

> Usó el arma que tenía a mano para defenderse. **Correcto**
>
> Usó la arma que tenía a mano para defenderse. **Incorrecto**

Sin embargo, en estos casos se invierte el artículo:

> El asesino usó el mismo arma que en sus últimos crímenes. **Incorrecto**
>
> El asesino usó la misma arma que en sus últimos crímenes. **Correcto**

¿A qué se debe ese cambio?

Comment: ¿Responden a tu pregunta las respuestas a [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/44/12637)?

Comment: Me ha servido el artículo que citan http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-agua-esta-agua-mucha-agua

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al enlace proporcionado por Charlie he podido indagar y encontrar lo [siguiente](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-agua-esta-agua-mucha-agua):

> **El agua, esta agua, mucha agua**
>
> El sustantivo agua es de género
> femenino, pero tiene la particularidad de comenzar por /a/ tónica (la
> vocal tónica de una palabra es aquella en la que recae el acento de
> intensidad: [água]). Por razones de fonética histórica, este tipo de
> palabras seleccionan en singular la forma el del artículo, en lugar de
> la forma femenina normal la. Esta regla solo opera cuando el artículo
> antecede inmediatamente al sustantivo, de ahí que digamos el agua, el
> área, el hacha; pero si entre el artículo y el sustantivo se interpone
> otra palabra, la regla queda sin efecto, de ahí que digamos la misma
> agua, la extensa área, la afilada hacha. Puesto que estas palabras son
> femeninas, los adjetivos deben concordar siempre en femenino: *el agua
> clara, el área extensa, el hacha afilada* (y no *el agua claro, el área
> extenso, el hacha afilado*).
>
> Por su parte, el indefinido una toma generalmente la forma un cuando
> antecede inmediatamente a sustantivos femeninos que comienzan por /a/
> tónica: un área, un hacha, un águila (si bien no es incorrecto, aunque
> sí poco frecuente, utilizar la forma plena una: *una área, una hacha,
> una águila*). Asimismo, los indefinidos alguna y ninguna pueden adoptar
> en estos casos las formas apocopadas (*algún alma, ningún alma*) o
> mantener las formas plenas (*alguna alma, ninguna alma*).
>
> **Al tratarse de sustantivos femeninos, con los demostrativos este, ese,**
> **aquel o con cualquier otro adjetivo determinativo, como todo, mucho,**
> **poco, otro, etc., deben usarse las formas femeninas correspondientes:**
> ***esta hacha, aquella misma arma, toda el agua, mucha hambre*, etc. (y no**
> ***este hacha, aquel mismo arma, todo el agua, mucho hambre*, etc.)**