# Definite article. el ala

Tags: artículos

I was wondering if "el ala" belonged to those group of nouns that start with an "a", where the definite article changes from LA to EL.

I also read that the indefinite article "UN" instead of "UNA" can be used before these nouns. I was wondering if this is an optional choice of a strict requirement.

Is "una ala" completely wrong or are both "un ala" and "una ala" correct?

Thank you.

Comment: We have a canonical question about the definite article before feminine nouns starting with a or ha https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la which gives much detail including _el ala_